# Javascript error swallowed in Dojo

Tags: javascript, logging, dojo, console.log, uncaught-exception

I'm using Dojo 1.8.1, and it often happens that in case of uncaught reference errors (eg: access to non existing function / variables / members of an object) the script will silently fail without any message on the console nor errors, making the debug process much much (much) slower!

Usually this happens after a chain of call to functions and (I could be wrong) it seems to happen more often after a rest call using the "dojo/request" object. This behavior could happen randomly, so the uncaught reference error could be thrown or swallowed without any prediction on the same line, most probably based on the caller of the function.

Here there is an example that I made with the described issue:

```
define([ "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/request", "dojo/ready" ], 
function(dom, domConstruct, request) {

    var prettyDate = function (millisecDate) {

        // wrong: console won't display the error, script will stop
        // uncaughtReferenceError['notExistingIndex']; 
        // uncaughtReferenceError.notExistingMethod(); 

        // if commented, script will stop at "return" line without errors on console
        var date = new Date(millisecDate);
        // same here, if commented "return" should throw the exception
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        // any misspell on the "date"  methods will cause the script to fail without logs (eg: getUTCYear() instead of getUTCFullYear())
        return  date.getUTCDate() + ' ' + months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCFullYear();

    };

    var startup = function(domNode) {

        // uncaughtReferenceError['notExistingIndex']; // correct: console will display the error and script will stop
        // uncaughtReferenceError.notExistingMethod(); // same here

        request.get("rest/repository/", {handleAs: "json"}).then(
                function(result){
                    var ul = domConstruct.create("ul", {  }, domNode);
                    result.repositories.forEach(function(repo) {
                        domConstruct.create("li", { innerHTML : prettyDate(repo.lastUpdated) }, ul);
                    });
                });

    };

    return { init: startup };

});
```

Dojo is configured with isDebug at true, but doesn't make a difference:

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        async : true,
        isDebug : true,
        parseOnLoad : true,
        baseUrl : "js/",
        packages : [ { name : "dsmonitor", location : "dsmonitor" } ]
    };
</script>
```

Here the correct page (everything is working, code is the one on top):
[image: everything is working]

Here if I put the error in the startup method (page load will stop but error is shown, uncaughtReferenceError is not commented in startup):
[image]

Here if I put the error in the prettyDate function  (page load will stop and no error is shown, uncaughtReferenceError is not commented in prettyDate, debug in real case scenario becomes hell):
[image]

I don't know if I am the only one experiencing this issue or if I'm doing something particularly wrong, but it happens in many of my projects (and I'm forced to put a huge amount of console.log call to understand what's going on) and I wasn't able to find any possible solution on internet!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this happen when the dojo library is imported from an external server (eg: *//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js*).

If I want to see non-expected errors in the console when a rest callback fails, I must have the dojo library on the same server/port of the website.

Since this slows down the development in Eclipse (validating the full library is heck slow), I found that [webjar](http://www.webjars.org/) could ease a bit the hustle!

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problems because your code is not waiting until the DOM is ready to be used.

You are using:

```js
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/request", "dojo/ready"],
  function(dom, domConstruct, request) {
  });
```

According to the [Dojo domReady](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/domReady.html) page, you should be using the domReady plugin like this:

```js
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"],
       function(dom, domConstruct, request) {}
);
```

As an alternative, if you want to use the ready function, you would have to do it like this:

```js
define(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/request", "dojo/ready"],
  function(dom, domConstruct, request, ready) {
    ready(function() {});
  });
```

Comment: Hi @mmckenzie, thanks for your interest! Unfortunately that's not the case, I didn't put the index.html file, but at its end I'm using the ready callback (in the way you mentioned) to call the init on the snippet I wrote above!